# Error 400 bad request but request isn't received by IIS

Tags: http, iis, http-status-code-400

i have to develop and http server to provide services for another software.

So i did the programming part and prepared the server (based on iis) and tested it with http client like postman/soapUI/... and everything works well.

The server is currently on a HTTP

When i tried with the software that should query my server, i saw with wireshark that it gets a reply 400 bad request - Invalid URL.

The software sent an encoded URI (%2Fcommand instead of /command). in the IIS log i don't even see any log of the software query... It seems like the http request doesn't even reach IIS.

Am i missing something ? I guess there is some parameters i need to correct to allow encoded URL ?

I tried to redirect with url rewrite every url to /command but even that doesn't make it (but it's working with postman,...).

I tried to modify register value :

AllowRestrictedChars => set to 1
EnableNonUTF8 => set to 1

I even tried to create a small nodeJS server to see if the problem lies with IIS but the results are the same (error 400 : bad request).

Thanks

Comment: You should configure `PercentUAllowed`, not `AllowRestrictedChars`.

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/iis/troubleshoot-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7) to see details about 400 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.